# mvc 2: filtering online vs offline users

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I understand that I could show online users using ajax. For example, I could detect and display if the user has been online or offline for last 5 minutes or 15 minutes etc.

How do I filter the users by online vs offline?

Or How do I filter the users by offline since 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 15 minutes etc etc.??

Since this logic will be in ajax, can i filter against the ajax results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LastActivityDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.lastactivitydate.aspx), this will show you who has been online. You can then query at will using ajax to a web method.